# Setting up website on IIS 10 local workstation 401.1 and 401.2 errors using windows auth

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have been going through other threads related to this, but for some reason I just cant get the past the authentication issue(s).  Im setting up a new website on my local windows 10 workstation,  leaving the default website intact.  Basically, doing the same steps as here
http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_up_two_web_sites_in_IIS7.aspx
- Setup an alias in my hosts file
- Setup the new website in IIS (in my case using v10)
- Enable windows auth, disable anonymous auth
- Set the app pool to run under [NETWORK SERVICE]
- Under windows auth, make sure "Extended protection" is set to "Accept" and Kernel mode auth is checked
- [NETWORK SERVICE] has full permissions to the root folder where the files for the website are located
- The windows auth providers are sorted so that NTLM comes first.

When I try to request the url by the alias I have in the hosts file, I get a 401.1 error.

As other testing, I dropped a simple test.html file in the root path and selected "browse" from my IIS admin tool and **it displayed**.  **Not so** when I selected an aspx file and tried to browse. Yet both failed when trying them via a url.

**[Update1]** 
When I try via url:
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized

Looking in the IIS log, I see lines like this
2016-08-29 18:04:02 127.0.0.1 GET /Default.aspx - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 - **401 2 5 571**

Comment: A. Publish the exact and full error message. B. Are you firing request to services sitting on the same IIS (not in another computer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that comes in mind is the infamous **Loopback Check**.

> loopback check security feature that is designed to help prevent
>   reflection attacks on your computer. Therefore, authentication fails
>   if the FQDN or the custom host header that you use does not match the
>   local computer name.

**Source:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Follow the solution given on the above link and it should solve the issue.

Comment: Arrrgh, I was afraid of this as ive seen it mentioned in the past.  I wonder how this guy got it to work
http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_up_two_web_sites_in_IIS7.aspx

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you. I marked this as the answer, but I wish there was another way.